# Disable selection by mouse in Microsoft Chart in a C# windows application

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

When clicking and dragging my mouse within a Microsoft Chart, it selects a chart area by default.  In the screenshot below you will see an example...the grey area is the part that has been selected with the mouse. Does anyone know how to disable this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set some properties on your ChartArea cursors to disable the user interactions :

```
myChart.ChartArea[0].CursorX.IsUserSelection = false;
myChart.ChartArea[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = false;

myChart.ChartArea[0].CursorY.IsUserSelection = false;
myChart.ChartArea[0].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = false;
```

Comment: By the way, if you want to enable Zooming/Panning with the mouse, please feel free to try this little mschart helper : https://bitbucket.org/grumly57/mschartfriend